# Выборка записей SQLite за текущий день

Tags: sql, sqlite

у меня имеется БД в которой есть поле с датой, дата записана в БД в милисекундах и имеет такой формат 1571923871639, записей несколько сотен и у каждой своя дата, подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать выборку тех записей дата которых совпадает с диапазоном текущих суток, то есть с 00:00 по 23:59.

Comment: `... WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN 1571875200000 AND 1571961600000`?

Comment: Так оно так) а если делать выборку завтра? Как это автоматизировать? чтобы руками каждый день запрос не править) вот главная задача)

Comment: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) * 1000, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 86399 SECOND)) * 1000;`

Comment: То есть на самом деле, вопрос у Вас не в том, как выбрать записи, а как вычислить эти значения миллисекунд для текущего дня? :)

Comment: @TotalPusher В Sqlite же вроде нет функции `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: @Yaant нет, мне просто нужно каждый день получать выборку строк с датой попадающей в диапазон времени с 00:00 по 23:59 текущего дня, не правя каждый день запрос выборки строк

Comment: Ну, тут два варианта, либо найти подходящие функции для работы с датой непосредственно в sqlite, либо вычислить эти два значения там, откуда Вы выполняете этот запрос.

Comment: `SELECT strftime('%s', date('now')) * 1000, (strftime('%s', date('now')) + 86399)* 1000;`